# Quarkus build failure with 3.3.2

Tags: quarkus

I am migrating an application on 2.16.0.Final to 3.3.2 version. and I am getting an issue in code generation.

In the original project, we have dependencies in the project that use javax namespace. So I have created another module with all the dependencies with javax namespace and used maven shade plugin along with eclipse transformer to create an artifact with jakarta classifier to import to the quarkus application pom.

```
    <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <shadedClassifierName>jakarta</shadedClassifierName>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"/>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>   
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.transformer</groupId>
  <artifactId>transformer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.5.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>jar</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>jar</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <rules>
      <jakartaDefaults>true</jakartaDefaults>
    </rules>
    <artifact>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </artifact>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now when I include this jakarta classified dependency, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.3.2:generate-code (default) on project rest-quarkus: 
Quarkus code generation phase has failed: 
Failed to bootstrap application in NORMAL mode: Failed to inject extension deployment dependencies for team.ajax.data:rest-quarkus:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Quarkus extension deployment artifact io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson-deployment:jar:3.3.2 does not appear to depend on the corresponding runtime artifact team.ajax.transformed:combined-dependencies:jar:jakarta:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.
```

Not sure how to debug this issue, any help is most welcome.
Thanks

Comment: It would help to know how shading is done. It looks like `io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson-deployment:jar:3.3.2` is somehow affected by it.